# Invalid syntax error in the print function

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, bots

I am learning how to make a discord bot in python.
I have this code:

```py
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN))
```

Which I took from a website and ran it on pydroid3. I then got an invalid syntax error on the print function.

Comment: Maybe u use Python2 and Not Python 3

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's just because you got `client.run(TOKEN))`<- !! There is another bracket! Maybe it's just a typo, but I can't find anything wrong in your print() statement. But maybe as user2672844 said, it's just the version and with that the **wrong** `print` function